# Invertibility of matrix with linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, inverse

Suppose we have the $4\times 4$ matrix $V$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cos{z_0} & \cos{2z_0} & \cos{3z_0}\\
1 & \cos{z_1} & \cos{2z_1} & \cos{3z_1}\\
1 & \cos{z_2} & \cos{2z_2} & \cos{3z_2}\\
1 & \cos{z_3} & \cos{2z_3} & \cos{3z_3}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Obviously the functions are linearly independent. Suppose moreover that $z_0=-z_3$ and that $z_1=-z_2$. Therefore, since $\cos{x}$ is even, we have that $V(1,2)=V(4,2)$ (1), $V(2,2)=V(3,2)$ and so on for each column.

Is this matrix singular?

(1) $V(1,2)$ is the element in row $1$, column $2$.

Comment: You really need to define your symbols as lately our adivinatory skills have greatly diminished...What is $\;V(1,2)\;$ and etc.??

Comment: This matrix must be singular. The first and third rows are the same, and the second and fourth rows are the same (although this information is not needed).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Obviously, such a stupid question. Now I see it, thanks.

Comment: No question is stupid, my friend. You are welcome.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes in this case yes. Because I substituted the entries of the matrix with letters (a, b, c...) to see that indeed the rows were equal (I knew in advance that the matrix was singular). But I put the letters in such a way that the columns are equal and I did not see it! Bey.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix will be singular when the rank is less than three:
$$
\rho < 3
$$
This will happen when at least one of the column vectors is a linear combination of the remaining column vectors.

This can happen, for example, when $\cos 2z_{0} = \cos z_0$...

Bad examples include
$$
  z_{k} = 2(k+1)\pi
$$